# How to have div horizontally scroll when resized.

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make content div show a horzontial scroll bar once the page becomes too narrow for the content inside of the content div. Currently, my setup is as follows:

[image: Current Display]

HTML:

```
<div id="LeftNavigation">
    <div id="TopNav">Menu1</div>
    <div id="BottomNav">Menu2</div>
</div>
<div id="ContentContainer">
    <div style="float: left; width: 500px">Content1</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Content2</div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#LeftNavigation {
    float: left;
}

#TopNav,
#BottomNav {
    width: 165px;
}

#ContentContainer {
    margin-left: 180px;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I'd like to have my page work like the image below. Where my content container has a minimum width of say...600 pixels and then when the page width gets below the combined width of the menu and content(including margins), a scroll bar shows up. I can't figure out how to get this to work properly, though. My ContentContainer div keeps wrapping below my LeftNavigation div whenever the page becomes too narrow. Thanks in advance.
[image: Desired Display]

Comment: Add a size to ContentContainer like @Diodeus explained, but in order for the scroll bar to appear like you want, you need to add a wrapper to all of your divs, and define the overflow-x:auto to that wrapper div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a size to `ContentContainer` and add `overflow-x:auto`. The scroll bar will show up on ContentContainer, not the entire page as you illustrate.

If you want it where shown in the diagram you'll need to make a fake scrollbar and use JavaScript to make it work.